# Best mouse for 3D/Blender for users used to Apple Magic Mouse?

Tags: mice

I use the Magic Mouse a lot. I find it extremely precise and convenient for text, video and design tasks.

[image]

I also like the way it looks, and the fact that it doesn't use a USB port.

Having recently started to learn 3D with Blender, I believe I am entering a domain that this mouse is clearly not designed for.

So I am looking for a mouse that would be good for 3D (three buttons, scroll-wheel in the middle), that doesn't look too ugly on my desk, and whose shape wouldn't be too different from the one of the Magic Mouse so that my hand can get used to it quickly when I switch back and forth. Also, it would have to be Bluetooth.

I looked on many websites, but the first thing that happens is that I can't find anything that seems to meet these requirements, or the second thing that happens is that most brands are brands I've never heard of and don't know whether I can trust them with my money or not. I'd rather avoid buying 20 different mouses (mice?) until I find one that works on Mac / is sturdy / works very well / etc.

So far I've been using a Logitech M185, which isn't very beautiful, and also needs a USB port to work (it's wireless, but you need to plug a transmitter/receiver in the USB port for it to work).

Comment: A *lot* of wireless mice use a USB transceiver. Straight BT mice do exist, but are expensive IIRC. Have you got any requirements about pricing?

Comment: Well, the Magic Mouse is straight-up right-up bluetooth, no USB thingie attached... And the Logitech one that I have, I still don't understand why it needs the USB thingie to connect to my computers since Bluetooth is standard on Macs... And to answer your question, I don't have a price range in mind. Below 200$ would be good lol

Comment: So Fabrice D, I'm having this problem also with blender, its a real pain, so to clarify you tried using BTT with the mighty mouse 2 and found it cumbersome? and then u used the Logitech M557 bluetooth miuse for blender and stuck with it? if so do u use the M557 just for blender and the might mouse for all other software?

Comment: Yes @patrick, I use the M557 most of the time, it's really good, and the M185 on the other computer, and also sometimes the Mighty Mouse (slightly more precise IMHO for illustrator/indesign/photoshop...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @ArtOfCode said in a comment, there aren't many mice out there that can connect directly to a device without a receiver. This is because most wireless components (Bluetooth or otherwise) are designed using their own special frequencies, encodings, or some other aspect that, when altered, can restrict freely connecting to any device. Most companies do this as a simple marketing technique.

Now for a recommendation. As always, good ol' Logitech has a product for anything you need. The [M557 Bluetooth Mouse](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/bluetooth-mouse-m557) (~$40 USD) will hopefully suit you well:

- Bluetooth wireless – no receiver needed to connect to any device
- 12-month battery life (kind of vague because everyone uses their mouse differently, still amazing though)
- Logitech software allows you to customize the function of each button
- 1000 dpi for accurate clicks
- Scroll wheel can scroll side-to-side
- Comfortable design – not nearly as slim as the Magic Mouse, but the shape is similar (see below)

[image: Apple Magic Mouse - Top View] [image: Logitech M557 - Top View]

Answer (score 3):

The Magic Mouse is totally perfect for Blender 3D. 
My argument though comes with a caveat, you need to install the Better Touch Tool (BTT) and add more gestures. (See picture attached).

Now you have middle click (By using 3 finger Click) and all the rest.

[image: Better Touch Tool]

I did buy the M557 as well but I sold it after awhile since I just love the magic mouse so much (Apparently with the help of BTT).

Comment: I should have aded to my original question that I really wanted to hang on to my magic mouse and tried very hard to make it work - yes that included trying out BTT. Not only BTT worked erratically, but the biggest problem I had was not being able to know by feeling with my finger where the middle button started or ended. I would click on the middle button by mistake, or have to redo the same gesture 3 times in 3d software because I wasn't "on" the middle button. The great advantage of a mouse with 3 physical buttons is not having to look at it: your fingers search for the button instinctively

Comment: @fabriced: On a laptop touchpad I had a similar issue of not knowing where the different areas ended and started. I cut a sticker into thin strips and put the strips on the borders. You can just feel them, and your fingers learn where they are in short order.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Logitec gaming mouse]

This is the absolute best mouse for blender IMHO.

It has a num pad directly on the side (totally programmable) and I usually like to set the far left trigger button to cmd+z because I make a lot of mistakes.

It literally changed my Blender game and I would hate having to adapt to something else.